# mongodb: match either string or array

Tags: mongodb

mongodb provides this syntax to match a string:

```
db.inventory.find( { tags: "red" } )
```

so it would match:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"), "tags" : "red" }
```

but it would also match an element in array:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"), "tags" : [ "blank", "red" ] }
```

so how can i match either a string or an element in array but not both?

i know i can use `$where` but for obvious reasons i prefer simpler approaches if any:

```
db.inventory.find({ "$where": "this.tags == 'red'" })
db.inventory.find({ "$where": "Array.isArray(this.tags) && this.tags.includes('red')" })
```

Comment: The typical way is to use `$exists` and look for the `0` index element, which means it is either an array or not.  i.e `{ "tags": "red", "tags.0": { "$exists": false } }` for a "string" or `true` for an array. That's more efficient than JavaScript evaluation. Also note the documentation of `$type` for the problems with "arrays" and "arrays of something" as a distinction.

Comment: @NeilLunn well the `$exists` trick has a caveat with object type having the same key, but in this case it seems to work fine because object type is excluded by the first clause;

Comment: Well if you are naming subdocuments with numeric key names, then you have other design issues to fix as a priority. Note also that `$type` can often be applied, but the usual case is the `0` index means there is "something in there" which `$type` cannot actually determine. And `$size` is far too specific.